# Curl returns successfully but shows 500 error, Internal server Error

Tags: php, curl, soap, webservice-client

I am accessing a web service using curl, but at times I get response but other times it fails with an Internal Server Error even though I actually receive the expected xml file. What could the problem be?

```
$header = array(
                  "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                  "Accept: text/xml",
                  "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                  "Pragma: no-cache",
                  "Content-length: ".strlen($send),
                );

            $URL = 'https:ip:port/xxxxx';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); //array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $send );
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
try {
                $result = curl_exec($ch);        
                curl_close($ch);
                $f = fopen("./Response.xml", "w");
                fwrite($f, $result);
                fclose($f);           
            } 
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $payments = "<DIV class = 'alert alert-danger'>Failed Transaction. Please try again</DIV>";
                     $error = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s")."\nError Number:".curl_errno($soap_do)."\n";
                     $error .=  "Error String:".curl_error($ch)."\n Matrucule: ".$matricule."\n------------------------\n";
                     $f = fopen("./Payment_Error_Log.txt", "w");
                     fwrite($f, $error);
                     fclose($f);
            }
```

Comment: code 500 often means the service you're calling crashed while working. So it could be a timeout problem, or a php_error inside the webservice you're calling

Comment: i actually received a response xml and i am able to save  it in a file. but the php script still run to Internal server error

Comment: don't you have anything in your logs then ? (curl, php...)

Comment: surprisingly no error on my log

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the server side code.. https:ip:port/xxxxx is returning error 500 when POSTing to it.

Could be a problem with the web service or with the specific parameters you're POSTing (`$send`).

Comment: i have confirmed the parameters for the service and the xml request format is correct

Comment: Does this web service return a valid response when CURLing to it? http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html (regular curl, not php-curl)

Comment: i actually received a response xml and i am able to save it in a file. but the php script still run to Internal server error

Comment: What returns the 500? The curl or the PHP script?

Comment: i dont know, my best guest is the curl, cos i tested the script locally and it worked

Comment: 1. Did you test the webservice in prod? 2. Where do you see the 500? When you load the page or when you print the curl's result?

Comment: some seconds after i loaded the page.

Comment: some seconds after i loaded the page. not from the curl result